# Call a MethodCallExpression with dynamic number of parameters

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I need to call the following :

```
public MethodCallExpression CreateLazyMethod(object instance, MethodBase foundMethodInfo)
{
    var orderedParameters = MethodParametersEvaluator.OrderParameters(foundMethodInfo.GetParameters());
    var paramExpressions = orderedParameters.Select(x => (Expression)Expression.Parameter(x.GetType())).ToArray();
    return Expression.Call((MethodInfo)foundMethodInfo, paramExpressions);
}
```

and resolve the parameters at run time Something like:

```
var callabel = CreateLazyMethod(instance, foundMethodInfo);
var runtimeEvaluatedParamsList=new object[]{1,654,};
callable.Invoke(runtimeEvaluatedParamsList);
```

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send it as `object[]` and then use specific item during method generation.

Basically for `"Test Long String".Substring(5);` code below will generate such method:

```
object DynamicMethod(object[] params)
{
    return "Test Long String".Substring((int)params[0]);
}
```

Disadvantage is that result and params are object so it will produce unneeded boxing\unboxing operations, but if you know signature, then you can write Generic implementation that will use specific types.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // test non static method with result
        string test = "Test String";
        MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Substring", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[]{typeof(int)},null);
        Func<object[], object> lazyMethod = CreateLazyMethodWithResult(test, method);
        object result = lazyMethod(new object[] { 5 });
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.WriteLine();

        // test static method with no result
        var staticMethod = typeof(Program).GetMethod("StaticMethod", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        var staticAction = CreateLazyStaticMethodWithNoResult(staticMethod);

        staticAction(new object[]{"Test message"});
        Console.WriteLine();

        //test static method with result
        var staticMethodWithResult = typeof(Program).GetMethod("StaticMethodWithResult", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        var staticActionWithResult = CreateLazyStaticMethodWithResult(staticMethodWithResult);

        Console.WriteLine(staticActionWithResult(new object[] { "Test message" }));
        Console.WriteLine();

        // sample with constructor
        var constructorCall = typeof(TestClass).GetConstructors().First();
        var constructorAction = GenerateLazyConstructorCall(constructorCall);

        var createdObject = constructorAction(new object[] { "Test message" });

        Console.WriteLine("Created type is " + createdObject.GetType().FullName);
    }

    //Test class
    public class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----Constructor is called with message - " + message);
        }
    }

    public static void StaticMethod(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("----Static method is called with " + message);
    }

    public static string StaticMethodWithResult(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("----Static method with result is called with " + message);
        return "Hello from static method";
    }

    public static Func<object[], object> CreateLazyMethodWithResult(object instance, MethodInfo method)
    {
        ParameterExpression allParameters;
        var methodCall = GenerateCallExpression(instance, method, out allParameters);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object[], object>>(methodCall, allParameters);
        return lambda.Compile();
    }

    public static Action<object[]> CreateLazyMethodWithNoResult(object instance, MethodInfo method)
    {
        ParameterExpression allParameters;
        var methodCall = GenerateCallExpression(instance, method, out allParameters);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<object[]>>(methodCall, allParameters);
        return lambda.Compile();
    }

    public static Func<object[], object> CreateLazyStaticMethodWithResult(MethodInfo method)
    {
        ParameterExpression allParameters;
        var methodCall = GenerateCallExpression(null, method, out allParameters);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object[], object>>(methodCall, allParameters);
        return lambda.Compile();
    }

    public static Action<object[]> CreateLazyStaticMethodWithNoResult(MethodInfo method)
    {
        ParameterExpression allParameters;
        var methodCall = GenerateCallExpression(null, method, out allParameters);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<object[]>>(methodCall, allParameters);
        return lambda.Compile();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Generate expression call
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="instance">If instance is NULL, then it method will be treated as static method</param>
    private static MethodCallExpression GenerateCallExpression(object instance, MethodBase method, out ParameterExpression allParameters)
    {
        var parameters = GenerateParameters(method, out allParameters);

        var methodInfo = method as MethodInfo;
        // it's non static method
        if (instance != null)
        {
            var instanceExpr = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(instance), instance.GetType());
            return Expression.Call(instanceExpr, methodInfo, parameters.ToArray());
        }

        // it's static method
        return Expression.Call(methodInfo, parameters.ToArray());
    }

    public static Func<object[], object> GenerateLazyConstructorCall(ConstructorInfo constructor)
    {
        ParameterExpression allParameters;
        var parameters = GenerateParameters(constructor, out allParameters);

        var newExpr = Expression.New(constructor, parameters.ToArray());
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object[], object>>(newExpr, allParameters);

        return lambda.Compile();
    }

    private static List<Expression> GenerateParameters(MethodBase method, out ParameterExpression allParameters)
    {
        allParameters = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]), "params");
        ParameterInfo[] methodMarameters = method.GetParameters();
        List<Expression> parameters = new List<Expression>();
        for (int i = 0; i < methodMarameters.Length; i++)
        {
            var indexExpr = Expression.Constant(i);
            var item = Expression.ArrayIndex(allParameters, indexExpr);
            var converted = Expression.Convert(item, methodMarameters[i].ParameterType);
            parameters.Add(converted);
        }

        return parameters;
    }
}
```

Real working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lHB2kE

**UPDATE**
I updated code with samples for calling methods and constructor:

1. Instance method with no return object
2. Instance method with some return object
3. Static method with no return object
4. Static method with some return object
5. Sample constructor usage

Comment: :Thanx how can I call a constructor like: `ctor.Invoke(new object[] { 10 })`

Comment: :And how can I call static (this gets me : Expression of type 'System.Boolean' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object')

Comment: I've updated answer with samples for static methods. If you need to call static method that returns `Boolean`, then you can check `CreateLazyStaticMethodWithResult` method and sample that uses it in `Main` method

Comment: About constructor there is the last sample in `Main` method with `GenerateLazyConstructorCall` method usage